# Subversion on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I updated a projected on my SVN using Subversion on Eclipse and there was a conflict. I resolved it by removing my version and just keeping it the way it is on the server. Now whenever I commit, it says there is still conflict. In the Team Perspective, I see zero differences! How can I sort that? I don't see how it still conflicts. When committing, it says the status of that class is still conflicted.

When I update, I get "At revision 21."

Btw, I run Mac OS X so I can't use Tortoise, and I won't use versions, its expensive.

Can I just overwrite the server with my file? This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the modified files out, revert on the parent folder above the conflicts, move the files back in. It's a pain but it works :)

Comment: Tried that 10 times but it JUST worked for some reason. Thanks..

Also, when I commit under "Resources" where I can check files to commit, I see Classname.class. What is that? Why is it .class? Everything I have is .java. How can I get rid of it from the list?  Thanks

Comment: If you're getting class files, check that your output dir (bin) is separate from your source dir (src), that the output dir is added to 'ignored files' on SVN. If you have versioning enabled on built files, you'll get all sorts of problems, since it deletes the files without updating the metadata.